# Expect script to deploy SSH key isn't working

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, expect

The goal of my script is to deploy my ssh key through ssh-copy-id to 100 of my server.

To achieve this goal I'm using 3 files.

#### CreateParam

```
#!/bin/bash
 while read line;
   do
     IPSrv=`echo $line | cut -d":" -f1`
     Login=`echo $line | cut -d":" -f2`
     Passwd=`echo $line | cut -d":" -f3`
     ./deployssh.sh $IP $Login $Passwd
 done < ServerList.txt
```

This script allow me to pass the IP, Login and Passwd as parameters for my expect script.

#### ServerList.txt

```
Name:@IP:RootLogin:Password
....
```

This file contains the Name, address IP, server's Root Login and Password.

#### deployssh.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set IPSrv [lindex $argv 1]
set Login [lindex $argv 2]
set Passwd [lindex $argv 3]

spawn ssh-copy-id $IPSrv@$Login -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
expect -re "password:"
send -- "$Passwd\r"
```

This expect script is supposed to deploy my ssh keys to all the servers mentioned  on the ServerList file. However it's not working for the moment.

I'm wondering what am I doing wrong, can you help me solve this issue ?

Comment: take a look at [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write *Expect* scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

1. You're using the wrong variable name: `IPSvr` vs `IP`
2. Looks like you have an off-by-one error: while parsing ServerList.txt you want fields 2, 3, 4

---

A bit of code review: you can simplify your parsing in the shell part -- the `read` command can split a line into fields. A bonus, this method allows you to put a colon in the password.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS=: read -r hostname IP Login Passwd; do
    ./deployssh "$IP" "$Login" "$Passwd"
done < ServerList.txt
```

And in expect, extract all words from argv in one command, and wait for the ssh-copy-id command to complete before exiting.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
lassign $argv IPSrv Login Passwd

spawn ssh-copy-id $IPSrv@$Login -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
expect -re "password:"
send -- "$Passwd\r"
expect eof
```

Or, as they're both quite short, combine them using the environment to pass the variables, and use a *quoted* heredoc so the shell does not expand the expect variables.

```
#!/bin/bash
export IP Login Passwd
while IFS=: read -r hostname IP Login Passwd; do
    expect <<'END_EXPECT'
        spawn ssh-copy-id $env(IP)@$env(Login) -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
        expect -re "password:"
        send -- "$env(Passwd)\r"
        expect eof
END_EXPECT
done < ServerList.txt
```